# how to filter by product type when we have some other types?

Tags: product, custom-product-type

```
$batt_pack = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$batt_pack->addFieldToFilter('product_type',
        array(
            'like' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute('product_type')
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId('Battery Pack')
            )
```

although I used "like" it shows me only the ones that has just the product type of Battery pack it doesn't show me the ones has battery pack **and** some thing else
how can I do that?

```
  ->getOptionId('Battery Pack%')
```

this one also didn't work
I know it is so wrong but I guess I should do something like this

Comment: I found my solution! it was easy! I added % in the end of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I thought! I should have the % in the end of my string like this:

```
$batt_pack->addFieldToFilter('product_type',
        array(
            'like' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getAttribute('product_type')
                        ->getSource()
                        ->getOptionId('Battery Pack').'%'
            )
        );
```